# Permutation and Combination: Why is my logic incorrect?

Tags: permutations, combinations

So, the question is,

"In how many ways can 6 persons be selected from 4 officers and 8 constables if at least one officer is to be included?"

I did this,

*4C1 x 11C5*

I first selected one officer from the 4 officers and then selected remaining 5 from the 11 persons remaining.

The answer I'm getting is wrong, the correct one is 896 which I got by subtracting the total number of combinations by using only constables minus all the combinations,

*12C6 - 8C6*

It would be great if someone can point out the mistake I committed in my first logic.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the combinations $O_1 C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4 O_2$ and $O_2 C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4 O_1$ ($O_i$ are officers, $C_i$ are constables). You count them as two different combinations, but are they really different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose the officers are ABCD and the constables are 01234567.

What you are counting are pictures of the shape

```
{ one letter } | { five characters }
```

Here are three *different* pictures of this shape

```
A | BC567
B | AC567
C | AB567
```

However, all three of these pictures describe the *same* selection ABC567. Thus, you've counted this *single* selection three different times, and get the wrong answer.

Comment: Oh! I get it now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Well, you pick the first person name $A$ and choose 5 remains which contains an officer name $B$.

After that, you pick the first person as $B$ and in 5 people are the same with the first way, but change $A$ to $B$. Two ways are the same, then you count twice.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!